# NGINX rewrite rule with exclusions

Tags: regex, url, nginx, url-rewriting, masking

I'm new to NGINX and horrible with regular expressions. This is what I need:
A rewrite rule that:

Masks mysite.com/SOMETHING over mysite.com/profile.html?id=SOMETHING

EXCLUDES mysite.com/images/ (and anything in that directory) from this rewrite

EXCLUDES mysite.com/ (the root directory) from rewriting

EXCLUDES mysite.com/ANOTHERFILE.html (or .php) from rewriting

I've done a lot of googling and can't seem to find what I need. Not even a support article that tells me more about the regex's nginx uses. This was my best guess:

```
 location / {
    rewrite ^(?!(/images/))(.*)$ profile.html?id=$2 break;
    return   403;
}
```

I put that in my nginx.conf file. It sort of worked. It would rewrite any request such as `mysite.com/SOMETHING` to `mysite.com/profile.html?id=SOMETHING`, however, it would also rewrite `mysite.com/` to `mysite.com/profile.html?id=`. The /images/ exclusion seemed to work (as my images loaded properly), however, even going to `mysite.com/index.html` would rewrite to `mysite.com/profile.html?=id=index.html`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with NGINX to give you a proper answer, but it sounds like you might want to use [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) so that you only rewrite URLs that don't actually exist as a file. For example, `index.html` does exist as a file, and therefore the URL shouldn't be rewritten. I'd say this might even cover your `images` case, since if the _directory_ exists, it shouldn't rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works, but I suspect that the regex matching is eating up some CPU time and  possibly slowing the performance of my site. I'm going to keep looking for improved solutions, but here's how I ended up solving the problem:

```
#Location routing for user accounts
location = / {
break;
}

location / {
    rewrite ^(?!(/images/|(.*\..*)))(.*)$ /profile.html?id=$2 break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1 break;
    return   403;
}
#end location routing for user accounts
```

I put that inside of the `server { }` block of my `nginx.conf` file. The first block, `location =/ {  }`, checks if the location is `/` (web root directory) and ONLY `/`, then do nothing different than normal server operation, and then that should escape all location handling/url rewriting.

Next, the `location / {` block matches any URI in the webroot. Here's where the `rewrite` and regex matching comes in. First, the rewrite engine tries to match the URI to the regex `^(?!(/images/|(.*\..*)))(.*)$`, which requires the URI not to start with `/images/` OR `file.ext` (anything in that format), and then takes any word, `(.*)`, and throws it into the rewritten url then all url rewriting breaks and the server serves the page.

If there's no match in the URI to the regex, for example, URI = `/images/arrow.png` or URI = `/folder/` or URI = `/profile.php`, then, it moves on to the next rule. The next rule just takes your URI and rewrites the same URI. I can't speak for the efficiency of this tactic, especially since you will never reach the `return 403;` statement, I feel like maybe there's a better way to do this. I tried using `try_files` but I had little success with that. This is working for now, and meets my criteria. Seems to be lacking in performance a bit, but I'll have to live with it until I can make improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think one rule could handle all of this, but I'll assume a couple of things and you need to confirm it.

for root location there's an index.php
for /images and /file.html I'll assume that those files exist with the exact path and serve them, I'll explain more after i write the rules

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com; # maybe www.mydomain.com too
    index index.php; # or index.html, depending on ur app structure
    location ~ /(.*) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?profile=$1;
    }
}
```

`/images/image.png` and `file.php`/`file.html` will all be matched by the first rule `$uri`, root will serve index.php (not very sure though) and when all fails (like your `/something` URL, it will try the `/index.html?profile=something`

ps: I would have used `$request_uri` instead of `$1` but it includes the first `/` so it would evaluate to `/index.html?profile=/something` and I assume that would not work with your code.

Comment: The `try_files` forwarder didn't seem to work for me for some reason when I tried it before. I'll play with this suggestion and see if it works better than my current solution. I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: does it show a 500 error? or a wrong response? and what's the error log for it if there's an error